# Bad access code when allocating a class containing a CGPoint and initializing it

Tags: objective-c, cgpoint

I have been trying to figure out what is the problem with the code I've written and I have not the slightest clue why is it wrong. Another thing I noticed was that Xcode is treating my CGPoint as a pointer, preventing me from using arrow notation. I need it to be a property for the purposes of my program
in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint* directionUsed;
```

in controller file

```
// up is just an instance of the class direction.
// Direction is a class that returns itself

self.up =    [[Direction alloc]initWithX:0 y: -1];
```

designated initializer in .m file:

```
-(id)initWithX:(int)x y:(int)y{

self = [super init];

if(self){
    self.directionUsed->x = x; //not letting me use dot notation
    self.directionUsed->y = y;
}
return self;
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you defined your CGPoint as pointer

just change your code

from

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint* directionUsed;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint directionUsed;
```

**Edit**

In order to assign a value to `directionUsed` you need to allocate the struct first
You need to change your code

from

```
self.directionUsed->x = x;
self.directionUsed->y = y;
```

to

```
CGPoint point;
point.x = x;
point.y = y;
self.directionUsed = point;
```

Comment: That solved most of my problems, however now I am unable to assign the values of the initializer to the CGPoint. eg. when I do 'self.directionUsed.x = x' on my initializer method it gives me an error saying the expression is not assignable.

Comment: I have updated my replay ... you can't change the values inside struct without creating the struct itself